# Terraform: How can I read a value from a json file?

Tags: terraform

I have the json file (*map.json*):

```
[
  {
    "QueueName": "queue1",
    "TypeName": "type1"
  },
  {
    "QueueName": "queue2",
    "TypeName": "type2"
  },
  {
    "QueueName": "queue3",
    "TypeName": "type2"
  }
]
```

which I can load into the following variable:

```
locals {
  maps = jsondecode(file("maps.json"))
}
```

How can I read the **TypeName** value for **QueueName** = "queue2"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at something like this:

```
type = [for el in local.maps : el["TypeName"] if el["QueueName"] == "queue2"]
```

**Output**

```
$ terraform console
> local.response
[
  "type1",
]
```

Logically this will return a list of elements, but if you want to retrieve only the first result, then you can use:

```
response = [for el in local.maps : el["TypeName"] if el["QueueName"] == "queue1"]
type     = length(local.response) > 0 ? local.response[0] : ""
```

**Outputs**

```
$ terraform console
> local.type
"type1"
>
```

Or just:

```
type = local.maps[index(local.maps.*.QueueName, "queue1")]["TypeName"]
```

But this will throw an exception if the element queueName does not exist, something like this:

```
Call to function "index" failed: item not found
```